# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) *Trying to build an array*

Tags: ruby, operators

I am getting the "undefined method '+'" eror on line 11. Not sure why.

```
#Make an array of Fibonacci numbers till 4 million
r=2
i=1
fibo=[1]
s=0
t=0

for r in 1..4000000
  r=fibo[i]
  t=fibo[i-1]
  s=r+t
  r+=s
  i+=1
end

puts fibo
```

Comment: Because for some `i`, `fibo[i]` doesn't exist.

Comment: You never modified `fibo`, it's always an `Array` that has one element.

Comment: Also, why are you using `for r in 1..4000000` and give `r` a new value immediately in the iteration? My suggestion is: learn how to debug, not necessarily an advanced debugger, just starts with using `puts` and `p` to output values of variables and debug.

Comment: Also dont use `for` loop. ruby has `each` and others

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question was - why is the error being shown? I think the term 'not sure why' makes that sufficiently clear. 
I figured out the answer. The assignment operator needed to be reversed. (See below.)

Answer (score 2):

In your assign fibo=[1] that means fibo[0] = 1 but what is the value of fibo[1] ?

```
fibo[1]  will be nill

r=fibo[i] # r = 1
t=fibo[i-1] # t = nil

s=r+t # will show undefined method for nill
```

To fix your issue, assign

```
 fibo[1] = 1
```

Comment: These are the changes I made:

fibo = []
fibo[0]=1
fibo[1]= 2

.....

  r=fibo[i]
  t=fibo[i-1]
  s=r+t
  r+=s
  i+=1
end

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your case fibo has only one element in array. you are trying to get element from index 1(i). which is causing error

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed by reversing how I wrote the assignment operator. Instead of

```
r=fibo[i]
t=fibo[i-1]
s=r+t
```

I did

```
fibo[i]=r
fibo[i-1]=t
s=r+t
```

This is because since the code is read right to left, the fibo[i] parts (which were nil) were being assigned to the variables. The variables then could not be operated on.

Once the initialized variables were instead first assigned to the array indices, the array indices were not nil, and the variables themselves could be operated on.